# Google place API returns same place for two different place with same name

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am using Google place API. While it works fine there is a case where it fails. Place API returns same place for "`Gorakhpur, Uttar pradesh`" and "`Gorakhpur, Haryana`". It returns "`Gorakhpur, Haryana`" for both places.

```
autocompleteFragmentSource = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment_source);
autocompleteFragmentSource.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        sourceAddress = (String) place.getAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An Error Occured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Now source address is same when I select `Gorakhpur, Uttar pradesh` and `Gorakhpur, Haryana` from google place autocomplete.

**Note:** There is no issue with other places having similar names.

Comment: Hi Mona Suri, can you share your code. Without it we won't be able to provide with a proper answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am using google placeautocomplete.